# Fetch React Native TypeError Cannot read property 'json' of undefined

Tags: react-native, fetch

[image: error screenshot]

i'm trying to upload file to server using fetch in react native, but then callback of fetch promise throw "[TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined]".[image: server code]
does anyone know how to solve it ? thank youu

Comment: try logging `res` and see what it shows. and also try to add fetch `.catch` to see if there are any errors

Comment: Please confirm your api end point, is it GET or Post or Put, then check api server accessible or not, then use tryCatch for api handle

Comment: Please go throw this guide  [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)